# Django AttributeError at /company-registration/

Tags: python, django

I have a User model, an ApplicantProfile model, and a CompanyProfielModel. A user can be of two types, an applicant or a company.
**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_applicant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_company = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    objects = MyUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

class ApplicantProfile(models.Model):
    GENDER_MALE = 0
    GENDER_FEMALE = 1
    GENDER_CHOICES = [(GENDER_MALE, 'Male'), (GENDER_FEMALE, 'Female')]

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_directory_path, storage=image_storage, null=True, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    interest = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    linkedin = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    github = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    facebook = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name

class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_directory_path, storage=image_storage, null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_directory_path, storage=image_storage, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name
```

*I have two URLs to create two different types of users. I can create applicants automatically right after a user registers from the applicant registration url, but I can't create companies from the company registration url.*

**views.py**

```
def applicant_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ApplicantRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            ApplicantProfile.objects.create(user=user)
            messages.success(request, "Account created successfully.")
            return redirect('applicant-feed')

    form = ApplicantRegistrationForm()
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, 'user/applicant/applicant-register.html', context)

def company_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CompanyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            CompanyProfile.objects.create(user=user)  # This line gives the error
            messages.success(request, "Account created successfully.")
            return redirect('company-feed')

    form = CompanyRegistrationForm()
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, 'user/company/company-register.html', context)
```

Any help is appreciated.
[Getting this error in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QM0b.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to error, looks like `CompanyProfile` is not a model class but something else. Is there a chance that you redefine it in views.py? Probably you also define a view with this name?

Comment: I defined my view and my model with the same name. Later I noticed it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure, glad it was helpful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use the form because you can create an account directly to any model like this function

```
def company_register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user = request.POST['user']
    image = request.FILES['image']
    about = request.POST['about']
    location = request.POST['location']
    start_date = request.POST['start_date']
    website = request.POST['website']
    logo = request.FILES['logo']

    profile = CompanyProfile.objects.create(user=user, image=image, about=about, location=location, start_date=start_date, website=website, logo=logo)
    profile.save()
    return Response('Done')
else:
    return Response('POST method only accepted')
```